# What is the formula for photo electric current?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I am looking for formulas equivalent to Richardson's law and Child's law ( space charge limited emission). What I want to know is, how much current would I get for given material, voltage, frequency and intensity of light. I know photo electric effect in general.

Comment: You should post this on EE stack exchange too....

Comment: https://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-dual-nature-of-matter-and-x-rays/determine-the-photoelectric-current/